# Jumping times on Borel sets away from zero are stopping times

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

The following comes from some remarks of Philip Protter at page 26 of the book *Stochastic integration and Differential* equations that I have not been able to prove yet.

Let $X$ a Levy process, under a filtration satisfying the usual conditions. If $\Lambda$ is a Borel set in $\mathbb{R}$ bounded away from zero (that is $0 \notin \bar{\Lambda}$), then the jumping times

\begin{align}
&T_{\Lambda}^{1} = \lbrace t \geq : \Delta X_{t} \in \Lambda \rbrace \\
&\vdots \\
&T_{\Lambda}^{n} = \lbrace t > T_{\Lambda}^{n-1} : \Delta X_{t} \in \Lambda \rbrace 
\end{align}
are stopping times.

**My attempt**
Since the filtration satisfies the usual conditions, we only need to prove that $\lbrace T_{\Lambda} < t \rbrace \in \mathcal{F}_{t}$.

Let $\epsilon := d(0, \Lambda) >0$ and $M:= ( - \infty, - \epsilon] \cup [\epsilon, \infty)$, I am trying to prove

\begin{align}
\lbrace T_{\Lambda} < t \rbrace = \left( \bigcup_{r \in [0, t) \cap \mathbb{Q}} \lbrace \Delta X_{r} \in \Lambda \rbrace \right) \cap \lbrace T_{M} < t\rbrace 
\end{align}
If we can prove this equation, we are done. This is due to the fact that $\lbrace T_{M} \leq t\rbrace \in \mathcal{F}_{t}$ since 
\begin{align}
\lbrace T_{M} < t\rbrace = \bigcap_{n} \bigcup_{r,s \in [0, t+1/n)\\ \vert r-s \vert < 1/n} \lbrace \vert X_{s} - X_{r} \vert  > \epsilon \rbrace 
\end{align}

We know that the "$\supset$" is the easy part, but the "$\subset$" part is the only part that I need to prove. I was trying to prove this by contradiction, and seems that it is the best way.

If $w \in \lbrace T_{M} < t\rbrace $ and $w \notin \lbrace T_{M} < t\rbrace $ is a contradiction. This can be done using lemmas of discontinuities and the fact that $d(0, \Lambda) >0$. However the part $w \in \lbrace T_{M} < t\rbrace $ and $w \notin \left( \bigcup_{r \in [0, t) \cap \mathbb{Q}} \lbrace \Delta X_{r} \in \Lambda \rbrace \right)$ is the difficult one.

Any hint will be welcome.

Comment: Not sure if this is similar, but the "debut theorem", which says that the *hitting* time of a Borel set is a stopping time, is nontrivial.  The proof I've seen involves the Choquet capacitability theorem.  So just on its face, I might not expect this to have an easy proof.

Comment: I don't think I believe your claimed equation.  Typically for each $r$ we have $\Delta X_r = 0$ a.s., so the event in parentheses is a countable union of null events, hence null.  But the event $\{T_\Lambda < t\}$ is certainly not a.s. equivalent to $\{T_M < t\}$.

Comment: In addition to Nate Eldredge's comment, the equality for $\{T_M < t\}$ does not seem to be completely true: consider a path $X_t = t - \epsilon \mathbb{1}_{[\sqrt{2},\infty)}(t)$. Then $T_M = \sqrt{2}$, but according to the right-hand side of the formula, we should have $T_M \ge 2$.

Comment: Thanks @Nate Eldredge. What you say about my claimed equation is true.

Comment: Thanks @Mateusz Kwasnicki for your answer it seems useful.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge, I was thinking about the "debut theorem", the problem is that these results are about hitting times, but not about jumping times. I was thinking about similar results for jumping times but the results seem very complicated. One good reference about this topic can be found in the papper of Richard Bass "The measurability of hitting times"

Answer (score 1):

(Note: this may not be the easiest solution).

Fix $r > 0$ small enough, so that $\Lambda$ is contained in $\{x \in \mathbb{R} : |x| > r\}$. Define
$$
  S_n = \inf\{t > 0 : t \in 2^{-n} \mathbb{Z} \text{ and } |X_t - X_{t - 2^{-n}}| > r \}
$$
and
$$
  S = \lim_{n \to \infty} S_n .
$$
Then $S_n$ is a stopping time (by a standard argument), and so $S$ is a stopping time. By right-continuity of $X_t$, $S$ is strictly positive. Right-continuity and existence of left limits implies that $|X_S - X_{S-}| \ge r$ (this, however, requires a somewhat lengthy argument). Furthermore, $S \le T_\Lambda$: if $|X_t - X_{t-}| > r$ for some $t > 0$, then $|X_u - X_s| > r$ for $u \ge t$ and $s < t$ sufficiently close to $t$ (again by right-continuity and existence of left limits), and so $S_n \le t + 2^{-n}$ for $n$ large enough.

Consider the sequence $S^{(k)}$ of $k$-th occurrence of $S$; that is,
$$
  S^{(k + 1)} = S^{(k)} + S \circ \theta_{S^{(k)}} ,
$$
where $\theta$ is the shift operator. (In other words, $S^{(k + 1)}$ is equal to $S^{(k)}$ plus the first time the shifted process $X_{S^{(k)} + t} - X_{S^{(k)}}$ enjoys $S$). Clearly, $S^{(k)}$ is a strictly increasing sequence of stopping times, which diverges to infinity (due to existence of left limits). It follows that the sequence $S^{(k)}$ captures all jumps larger than $r$, and possibly some jumps of length equal to $r$.

It is now relatively easy to see that
$$
  T_\Lambda = \min \{S^{(k)} : X_{S^{(k)}} - X_{S^{(k)}-} \in \Lambda\},
$$
and so $T_\Lambda$ is a stopping time. (Here we use measurability of $X_T$ with respect to $\mathcal{F}_T$ for a stopping time $T$).